# Locked out from system after adding Yubikey 2FA

Tags: login, password, yubikey

I followed the [official Yubico guide](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-pam/Authentication_Using_Challenge-Response.html) to enable Challenge-Response 2FA on my account, However on a reboot the login prompts for the Yubikey, then asks for my password, and then repeats these 2 prompts with no end. If I switch to a TTY and attempt to login with root, I get an Authentication Failure message after it prompt for both the Yubikey and my password. For now, I just want to find a way to disable 2FA so that I can diagnose and fix the problem in my own time.
My question is, If I boot with a live CD and simply comment out the line in the PAM configuration file, will that be sufficient to allow me to get back into my laptop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot rom a live CD.

Mount your root file system at some place, and bind mount `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys`.  Assuming your root file system is mounted at `/mnt` in the live session, the following commands will do this:

```
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Then you have to chroot to your system

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Edit your PAM configuration and comment out the relevant line, like you suggested - and after saving the file, run `pam-auth-update` and disable the yubikey module.

Comment: Thank you very much, You commented just as I was about to try that myself. Did the trick

Comment: Just a further note that this option does not appear in the latest menu; you can either disable all of SSS, or keep it enabled. :facepalm: —see my hack below for how I got around this.

Comment: Is this really possible? what would then be the point of the key if you can just disable it like this?

Comment: @MarkoBlazekovic Stop remote attackers - and in combination with disk encryption, this would stop local attackers without the encryption secrets. There's simply *NO WAY* to stop someone from messing with the configuration if they have access to the configuration. That's a universal constant in security.

Answer (score 2):

For my case, if I pulled the Yubikey out, I could get in using regular password login. I then moved the following files to `/etc/pam.disabled`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   31 Apr 29 23:40 gdm-smartcard -> /etc/alternatives/gdm-smartcard
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.3K Feb 25 11:42 gdm-smartcard-pkcs11-exclusive
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.4K Feb 25 11:42 gdm-smartcard-sssd-exclusive
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.4K Feb 25 11:42 gdm-smartcard-sssd-or-password
```

i.e.,

```
sudo -i
mkdir /etc/pam.disabled
cd /etc/pam.d
mv *smartcard* ../pam.disabled/
```

You can then test by plugging in the Yubikey, locking the screen (Super+L or Lock if your keyboard has it), and you should see your happy familiar password prompt instead of the smartcard prompt.

Nit: Just because I install smartcard software doesn't mean I want to login that way. This wasn't happening just a few versions ago. There should be a way to install the PKCS11 drivers without enabling them for PAM challenges.