# Yubikey inserted always asking for smart card login and no longer for password

Tags: login, login-screen, gdm, smartcard

I'm using Ubuntu 23.10. My company provided me a Yubikey for VPN access and everything works fine. However whenever I turn my pc on, the gdm screen only asks for smart card login (and no longer for password login). I must unplug the Yubikey each time to let gdm prompt me with the normal unix user+password screen.

How can I configure it to not ask for smart card login at startup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locked out from system after adding Yubikey 2FA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062796/locked-out-from-system-after-adding-yubikey-2fa)

Comment: If that doesn't work, try https://askubuntu.com/a/1369690/1004020

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Smartcard Integration in Hirsute?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339157/disable-smartcard-integration-in-hirsute)